# What is this JSX / JS notation?

Tags: javascript, jsx

What is this notation with the backticks in this expression?

```
{room.type === 'upgrade' && i18n.t(`product.room.upgrade`)}
```

Comment: These are Template Literals: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: Thanks,  Matt, I didn't know of this.  Might be useful

Comment: I'm not sure why it's being used in this context though, just regular string would be fine.